# cast to std::thread states calling a private constructor

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, compiler-errors

Given a vector of `std::thread`

```
std::vector<std::thread> vThreads;

vThreads.push_back(std::thread([]() {
        std::thread _t;
        _t.detach();
    }));

for (int i=0; i < vThreads.size(); i++)
{
    std::thread _t = (std::thread) vThreads.at(i); <!-- ERROR


}
```

trying to perform the cast in the `for loop` I get: `Calling a private constructor of class 'std::__1::thread'`

But looking at `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/thread/thread/` I dont see anything constructor marked as private.

What do I misunderstand?

Comment: Try: `std::thread& _t = (std::thread) vThreads.at(i);`

Comment: You can't copy threads. What would that mean? Why would you want it? Code like that that's divorced from real problems is a bit useless.

Comment: Your lambda is also missing a return.

Comment: You can't `detach` a thread that is not joinable. A default constructed thread object (e.g., `_t` in the lambda expression) does not correspond to a thread of execution.

Answer (score 5):

`std::thread` is not copyable. Depending on what you indent to do within the `for` loop, you want either

```
std::thread& _t = vThreads.at(i);
```

or

```
std::thread _t = std::move(vThreads.at(i));
```

---

I'd recommend using a range-based for to loop through the `vector`

```
for(auto&& t : vThreads) {
  // t is a reference to an std::thread object
}
```

Comment: Why is `auto&&` used instead of `auto&`?

Comment: @0x499602D2 Neither makes a difference in this particular example